# Prepend selected characters at random to pad four and five long codes to length ten

Tags: excel, vba, char

I have some price codes, for example `BBAXV` and `GGZT`. I want to lengthen these to ten characters each by prepending letters other than: F,B,A,G,O,J,L,C,E at random. For example:

```
BBAXV to ZKXMIBBAXV
GGZT to VWWPDRGGTZ
```

I've trying use `Len` and `CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)` ...

Is there any way to generate a random string from a selection of letters and then combine that with the current price code?

Comment: char only, im editing it now. Sorry for that

Comment: I think yes, all letter except F,B,A,G,O,J,L,C,E. But it okay if not

Comment: Its mean okay. Range restricted to 80:95 the formula could be quite simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-D5F9E25C-D7D6-472E-B568-4ECB12433028) with [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685) supplying the starting position for each additional letter from a list of the unassigned letters.

```
=mid("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", randbetween(1, 17), 1)
```

However, you are going to have to know how many characters to start with or simply supply too many and truncate off the excess.

```
=RIGHT(MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        MID("DHIKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", RANDBETWEEN(1, 17), 1)&
        A1&"", 10)
```

[image: Ten Random letters]

That might look complicated but in fact it does a lot less work than the other array formula you received with INDIRECT. Yes, you can use that formula exactly as it is so that the line feeds can help readability.

Answer (score 0):

As your idea, please try:

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90))&IF(LEN(A1)=4,CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(80,90)),"")&A1
```